# https issue - after clicking hyper link

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

When i click a link in one page called **a.html**, the target link(b.html) will be have to be opened, which is an secure site SSL (https).

After i clicked the a.html site, the b.html site not opened instead it was saying the site can't be reached.

> What issue i saw was the **https://** is removed, i don't know why it
>   is removed.

Does any have any idea why this issue is occurring....

> **a.html** Testing....
>
> **b.html** https://test.abc.com/b.html - not opening because (https://) is removed.

Comment: Where are you testing the `https://` link? I suppose you are trying to test in local and the page don't have `https`.  If you could elaborate your question more we could help you more.

Comment: It is not the local URL, it is a dev site URL. The a.html page is not https site, but the link which i click, right is a https:// url. So when i click the link b.html is not opening, (because it is actually removing the https://), i'm being a Front End developer, don't have much idea on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested from my local and is working. Just have a look at this small block of code that only has link to the `google home page.`

**a.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">Google link from non https html</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It should work if you have a `https` site or page working from anywhere.

Edit:

In the case of not working there should be some reasons like :

1. Some codes might be removing your https links like: jQuery codes.
2. There might be some redirection codes like `htaccess`.

Or there might be some scenarios like that.

Comment: Yes I accept the your above code is working. (me too tested it just now). But our site link when clicked, is removing the https://. If i could share the link, I could have shared the link but it is restricted.  Do you have any suggestions like what might be the reason

Comment: @PCA I have added some scenarios in the above answer. There might be some sort of codes like i have mentioned.